# Running react tests after long time shows error unexpected token error dot

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

When running React tests I am facing below error. I am using create-react-app
I googled for solutions, few of them say to modify webpack config which we do not customize

Test suite failed to run

```
/Users/.../projects/node_modules/react-table/react-table.css:1

SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

below is jest.conf.json

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  coverageReporters: ["lcov", "text"],
  suiteName: "jest tests",
  output: "test/junit.xml",
  classNameTemplate: "{classname} - {title}",
  titleTemplate: "{classname} - {title}",
  ancestorSeparator: " > ",
  usePathForSuiteName: "true",
  testURL: "http://localhost/",
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"  ]
};
```

Below is Package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.5.5",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-webpack": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.0",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^2.1.30",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "britecharts": "^2.9.2",
    "browser-locale": "^1.0.3",
    "bytes": "^3.0.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "crypto-browserify": "^3.12.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
    "d3-selection": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "dom-to-image": "^2.0.6",
    "eslint-config-react-tools": "^1.1.2",
    "fast-memoize": "^2.5.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.69.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.30.1",
    "https-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.5.1",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jest": "^22.4.3",
    "jest-css-modules": "^2.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.3.5",
    "lint-staged": "^7.0.5",
    "loadash": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.5",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "moment-with-locales-es6": "^1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "^1.3.5",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.1",
    "os-browserify": "^0.3.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "query-string": "^5.1.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.19.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
    "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^4.1.0",
    "react-calendar": "^2.14.0",
    "react-contextmenu": "^2.8.0",
    "react-cropper": "^1.0.1",
    "react-data-grid": "^2.0.73",
    "react-data-grid-addons": "^2.0.73",
    "react-dom": "16.9.0",
    "react-files": "^2.4.3",
    "react-grid-layout": "^0.16.0",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.11.0",
    "react-iframe": "^1.1.0",
    "react-intl": "^2.4.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.3.1",
    "react-modal": "^3.3.2",
    "react-onclickoutside": "^6.7.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-redux-loading-bar": "^3.1.0",
    "react-router": "4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-saga": "^0.2.6",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.3",
    "react-select": "^1.1.0",
    "react-sortable-tree": "^2.1.1",
    "react-table": "^6.8.6",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "redux-form": "7.1.2",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-router": "^2.1.2",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "shx": "^0.2.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0"
  },
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/node": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^21.1.8",
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.3.1",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "eslint": "^4.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^3.1.0",
    "jest-junit": "^3.4.1",
    "json-server": "^0.12.1",
    "prettier": "^1.12.1",
    "prettier-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.3.2",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.4.0",
    "redux-devtools-dock-monitor": "^1.1.2",
    "redux-saga-testing": "^1.0.5"
  },
  "jest-junit": {
    "suiteName": "jest tests",
    "output": "test/junit.xml",
    "classNameTemplate": "{classname} - {title}",
    "titleTemplate": "{classname} - {title}",
    "ancestorSeparator": " > ",
    "usePathForSuiteName": "true"
  }
```

Below is BabelRC

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "react-app",
    "@babel/preset-flow",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        "corejs": 2
      }
    ],
    [
      "react-intl",
      {
        "messagesDir": "./src/assets/i18n/messages",
        "enforceDescriptions": false
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Could someone point me what could be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `moduleNameMapper` config for you `.css` (or any other static assets) file which you do not need to include in your test. so add a [moduleNameMapper](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack#handling-static-assets) config in your jest config file and point it to some where with a mock file. [example](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3094) :

```js
{
  "moduleNameMapper":{
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js",
      "\\.(gif|ttf|eot|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js"
  }
}
```

and your mock file looks sth like:

```
module.exports = {};
```

Comment: Thank you, That resolved the above error, now I see a new error "SyntaxError: /Users//Documents//projects//src/components/common/chart-layout/ChartHeader.js: [React Intl] Messages must be statically evaluate-able for extraction."

Comment: @user804401 Actually I do not get enough detail of your comment but maybe you could ignore that files